# Mongodb not listening on all interface

Tags: mongodb, nosql, unix

Infrastructure : I have 3 virtual machines ip in a DMZ on a same lan.
one of them is running mongodb . OS : RHEL

Mongod.conf : I have commented out the bindIP option

But still mongodb is not accpeting connection from other servers on LAN. Telnet is failing from other 2 servers

the netstat output is

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24251/./mongod
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1508/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1621/master
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1508/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1621/master
```

i m guessing the foreign address for 27017 port should also look like ":::*" 
I m not able to catch the problem here.Please help!

Comment: The `:::*` syntax is the IPv6 equivalent of IPv4's `0.0.0.0:*` (aka "all addresses"). I would check for firewall rules that may be blocking inbound access to `27017`.

Comment: @Stennie the local firewall is already disabled

Answer (score 3):

If you have firewall running, allow connections on port 27017, MongoDB default port.

Not sure which RHEL version you are running so below commands might change.

**1. Any connections can connect to MongoDB on port 27017**

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT
```

**2. Only certain IP can connect to MongoDB on port 27017**

```
iptables -A INPUT -s <ip-address> -p tcp --destination-port 27017 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d <ip-address> -p tcp --source-port 27017 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT


For Eg:

    iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.6.100 -p tcp --destination-port 27017 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.6.101 -p tcp --source-port 27017 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Also i personally believe commenting bind option is not a good idea.

Instead you can use below in /etc/Mongod.conf :

```
# Listen to local and LAN interfaces.
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1,x.x.x.x, x.x.x.x
```

and then

```
service mongod restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Alongwith the above Answer provided by @Sachin Singh

Please Check /etc/hosts file and add your IPaddress and Hostname,
not sure which RHEL version you are running so below commands might change.

Ex:

```
 192.168.6.100        hostname.domainname.com       hostname
```